# Step-chart in Excel

Tags: excel, charts, excel-charts

I am trying to create step-chart in Excel using [tutorial](http://peltiertech.com/Excel/ChartsHowTo/StepChart.html) (section "Step Chart Approach 2: Line Chart with Repeated Ranges").

However, it works incorrectly.
According to instructions (section "How it Works") values from 2 named ranges should be shuffled, while I get consequent values from 2 ranges.

The resulting Series formula seems to be correct:

```
=SERIES(Sheet1!$B$59,('Book1.xlsx'!KPInames2,'Book1.xlsx'!KPInames),('Book1.xlsx'!reqKPI2,'Book1.xlsx'!reqKPI),1)
```

(I am using namedRange**2** instead of namedRange**X**)

What am I doing wrong? How to force excel to mix values from 2 ranges?

Comment: Figured out that this trick with step-chart needs date axes. However, I need categories... Shurely, there is a bad way to create chart using date axes and afterwards overlap categories axes as a picture or someting. Is there any better way to do what I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was really in category axis insted of required dates axis. 
So the solution is to create a series with dates axis insted of needed category axis. And afterwards to create dummy invisible category series on the secondary axis.
Finally, playing with axis placement and visibility will produce required result